# Arabic X axis values letters display in a bar chart by matplot are not connected

Tags: python, matplotlib, arabic-support

It's about Arabic language in matplot. Python3 is already retrieving the object encoded, but the letters are not connected.

I already used `arabic_reshaper` and `bidi.algorithm`:

```
top20_sa.plot(kind="bar",x=get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(u"content_name")),y='time_spent_avg')
```

It looks like this:

[image: plot]

While the arabic text should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Did you try printing the encoded arabic text by a simple print? Mayibe it could not be a problem of matplotlib but how it is encoded and represented.

Comment: @Cowflu printing the text itself works fine